# nginx server directive is not allowed here

Tags: nginx, configuration

I know there are dupes of this out there, but I can't seem to solve this in my situation.

I'm following an article  on setting up nginx as reverse proxy with apache.

And I get this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in 
       /etc/nginx/v.hosts/mydomain.com.conf:3
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

My `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` looks like this:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream; 
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;  
    charset   utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server_tokens       off;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         off;

    server {
          listen 80;
          server_name  _;          
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index  index.html index.htm;     
       }
    }
include  v.hosts/*.conf;
```

And this I have `/etc/nginx/v.hosts/mydomain.com.conf` looks like this:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name  mydomain.com;

       access_log  off;
       error_log off;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_send_timeout 90;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        client_max_body_size 10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffer_size 4k;
        proxy_buffers 4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
      }
 }
```

Clues and help will be well appreciated :)

Comment: Removed all links, as they are dead now.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    }
include  v.hosts/*.conf;
```

You have closed the `http` block before the `include` directive, thus ending the configuration. This is why none of the included files work.

To fix the issue, `include` the files within the `http` block:

```
    include  v.hosts/*.conf;
}
```