# Nginx conf failed cause of server directive not allowed

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with one of my vhost. When I restart nginx, it's fail.

So I tried :

```
nginx -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/website -t
```

And here is my problem :

> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-available/website:1

I looked at this post : [nginx server directive is not allowed here](https://serverfault.com/questions/466486/nginx-server-directive-is-not-allowed-here) but my nginx.conf is correct, I don't have his problem.

Here is the content of website config :

```
server {
        server_name www.weacms.com;
        root /home/ebuildy/website/weacms;
        index index.html index.php;

        pagespeed on;
        pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                location = /index.php {
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
        }

        location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                expires 168h;
                log_not_found off;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revali$
        }
}
```

My config is included in nginx.conf :

```
        ...
        # Virtual Host Configs    
        #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Does someone see where is the problem ? thanks.

Comment: please show `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` have you included `website.conf` to `nginx.conf`

Comment: Question updated, my nginx.conf is the basic one, all conf are included. I have only website.conf, and the default.conf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't test your complete configuration, just the subsite defined in the file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/website`. This is not a valid `nginx` configuration file on it's own.

Try it with `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` or wherever your main config file is located.

Comment: Damn ! Thanks for this explanation ! I had an other error located in the default conf. Thanks a lot ! You saved my day.

Comment: may `service nginx configtest` without path to config.